# Multithreading in list halts main

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I'm working on a computercheck program, with several checks.
Once the checks are completed, the results will go into a database.
So far so good.
Since separate functions were freezing the application (wx based), I introduced threading in the code. Which work fine and fast.
The threading looked like this:

```
   check2 = thread2()
   check3 = thread3()
   check3 = thread4()
   check4 = thread5()

   check1.start()
   check2.start()
   check3.start()
   check4.start()
   check5.start()
```

The above is a def and is initiated by a button press event.
This all works well. Now I have to upload the results into a database. When I add the function e.g. uploadDB(arg[]) after the code, the function will start although the threads are still busy.

Which means I have to wait with that untill finished. Hence I'm now using the code a bit different like:

```
threads=[]
c1 = check1()
threads.append(c1)
c2 = check2()
threads.append(c2)
...
for x in threads:
   x.start()
        
# wait for all threads to finish
for x in threads:
   x.join()

uploadDB(arg[])
```

This works as well, but during the join, the interface freezes again, because everything is waiting until the threads are finished...and the freezing is actually what I don't want...but If I don't use the join...I don't know when the threads are finished before uploading..
There should be a more easy way to do this I suppose?

Thanks again for the help!~
/Jasper

Comment: Is the "threads.append(2)" a typo in your post or it's actually in the code you try to run?

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo...should say (C2) of course..

Comment: `join()` is blocking. If you don't want it to block your main thread/loop, you'll have to move it to its own thread. Or refactor your check threads in a way that would make the join unnecessary, if at all possible, e.g. make _them_ do the DB operation on the chunks of data they checked.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but since I'm learning threads... How can I move something out of the main into its own thread?

Answer (score 0):

An interim solution I have now is that I have a thead listener running. Every thread is posting a "run" to the listener and that one is keeping an integer for the amount of threads. At the end of a thread (wx.callafter) a "done" is posted and the integer is decreasing again. So when the integer is 0, it means all the threads are done and I can continue with e.g. database stuff.
However, this seems not to be a real efficient way of checking if the threads are done.
But the problem remains. "join()" is freezing...and if I set a while loop, I basically create the same situation as with the join() statement...it freezes the application..
So any suggestion of how to do this more efficient is welcome!

Thanks!